# jQuery UI draggable: bind to object in mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need to be able to set HTML objects as jQuery UI draggables dynamically in a `mousemove` event; this is because some objects on a page are dynamically created *under* the cursor.

Naive approach doesn't work (because, I guess, draggable() binds to `mousedown` event). Is there any way to hack into the jQuery UI draggable plugin, so I can assign it to element on `mousemove` and start dragging it immediately?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're talking about making a new element drag without stopping the current mouse movement, I believe it has been asked lot of times and it's almost impossible.

Comment: @TJ "So you're telling me there's a chance?"

Comment: @snookieordie I haven't seen it being implemented  using jQuery UI anywhere so far. Really, if it was possible someone would've done that already. But just because I haven't seen it so far, I can't make a statement that it's impossible. But I can say that if it's possible, it's sure gonna be hard ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually not that many things in the way of faking a drag start without a real **mousedown**. It will probably cause a lot of side effects though, especially if you want to combine with other plugins such as **droppable** or **sortable**, but depending on what you're looking for it might be good enough.

Here's a basic example, you can probably extend it so as to match your needs:

```js
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  // for this example when you move over x = 200 an element is created
  // and dragging starts
  if (e.pageX > 200) {
   
    
    // you create the element
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(newEl);
    newEl.classList.add('new');
    
    // set as draggable
    $(newEl).draggable();
    
    // get the instance
    var dragIns = $(newEl).draggable('instance');
    
    // trigger a mousedown with a which parameter to fake a left click
    $(newEl).trigger({type: 'mousedown', which: 1});
    
    // you set some variable and call some methods directly
    // on the instance to override normal behaviour
    dragIns._mouseStarted = true;
    
    // for mouse start you need the info of the mousemove event
    dragIns._mouseStart(e);
    dragIns.offset.click = {
      left: 8,
      top: 8
    };
 
    // run this only once
    window.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.new {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<div>

</div>
```